# Is there a way to "host" an existing web service on port X as a network path of another web service on port 80?

Tags: linux, web, flask, self-hosting

What I'm trying to do is create an access website for my own services that run on my linux server at home.

The services I'm using are accessible through <my_domain>:<respective_port_num>.
For example there's a plex instance which is listening on port X and transmission-remote (a torrenting client) listening on port Y and another custom processing service on port Z

I've created a simple website using python flask which I can access remotely which redirects paths to ports (so <my_domain>/plex turns into <my_domain>:X), is there a way to display these services on the network paths I've assigned to them so I don't need to open ports for each service? I want to be able to channel an existing service on :X to <my_domain>/plex without having to modify it, I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have a bit of a hard time to understand your question.

You certainly can use e.g. **nginx** as a reverse proxy in front of your web application, listen to any port and then redirect it to the upstream application on any port - e.g. your Flask application.

Let's say, my domain is example.com.

I then can configure e.g. nginx to listen on port 80 (and 443 for SSL), and then proxy all requests to e.g. port 8000, where Flask is running locally.

Comment: thanks for the input, I'll read up on nginx/reverse proxies maybe that's the solution, my goal simply put is transparently accessing a service on <my_domain>:<port_num> at <my_domain>/<service_name> instead without changing the service behaviour.

Comment: you don't need flask at all, use nginx reverse proxy instead. see https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-a-http-request-to-another-port

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called using nginx as a reverse proxy. It is well documented on the internet and even the [official docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). Your `nginx.conf` would have something like:

```
location /my/flask/app/ {
    # Assuming your flask app is at localhost:8000
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

From user's perspective, they will be connecting to `your.nginx.server.com/my/flask/app/`. But behind the scenes nginx will actually forward the request to your app, and serve its response back to the user.

You can deploy nginx as a Docker container, I recommend doing this as it will keep the local files and configs separate from your own work and make it easier for you to fiddle with it as you learn. Keep in mind that nginx is only HTTP though. You can't use it to proxy things like SSH or arbitrary protocols (not without a lot of hassle anyway). If the services generate their own URLs, you might also need to configure them to anticipate the nginx redirects.

BTW, usually flask is not served directly to the internet, but instead nginx talks to something like Gunicorn to handle various network related concerns: https://vsupalov.com/what-is-gunicorn/